# Image capture using iphone and go to the next view without showing the first view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to make an application that ,in my view there is a button for taking picture using camera in iphone. After taking the picture without coming to firstview go to the next view and there i need to show that picture in an uiimageview . I know how to take picture using camera and display it in an Uiimageview of the first view.

Firstview->buttoon for taking camera->secondview->uimageview with picture

Comment: And you are waiting for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same scenario , try like this

when Button Click - push SecondViewController with Animated:NO then

in your viewDidAPpear call the Camera Class - then after finishing , set the image of the imageview in your didfinishpickimage delegate of Imagepickercontroller.

Hope this Works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

in imagePicker's delegate method didFinishPickingMedia

get the UIImage object

then

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
//imageView is an IBOutlet UIImageView object and should be created using properties in SecondViewController you know what I mean (@property,@synthesize)
second.imageView.image = image; //you got using imagePicker
[second release];
```

That's all